# Action Bar menu in Fragment doesn't appear

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I am trying to create an Action Bar with one option in a fragment but it doesn't work.
And I have followed all the steps which are indicated in the internet tutorials:

1. Create the function "**onCreate**", it doesn't appear by default, with the "**sethasoptionmenu(true)**".
2. Write the function "**onCreateOptionsMenu**" with the "**inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fotos, menu);**"
3. Create the function "**onOptionsItemSelected**"

With this, what I get is a normal options menu. But what I need is an Action Bar menu!
Can you help me?

I copy here the code of the fragment:

```
    package com.carlesqf.laguerra;

    import *.*;

    public class FragmentContingutCapitols extends Fragment {   

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_contingutcapitols, null);        
            // Getting the bundle object passed from "PantallaContingutCapitols"  
            Bundle b = getArguments();      
            String nomcap=LlistaCapitols.name[b.getInt("position")];
            if (nomcap.contains("1700-1701 Les causes del conflicte:"))
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.capitol1700, null);
            else if ((nomcap.contains("1702 – Primers combats. Itàlia i front del Rin:"))) 
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.capitol1702, null);
... 
            return v;
        }   

        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            // Do something that differs the Activity's menu here
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);      
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fotos, menu);  
        }   

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
               // do s.th.
               return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the actionbar menu is a normal options menu. Is NavigationDrawer what you're looking for?

Comment: What I am looking for is a system to return from the fragment B, where the user can read the contents of a chapter, to the fragment A, where there is the index of the differents chapters. I could use the default buttons of the phone.But it would be better an action bar.